# Read Access Violation when accessing a QBarDataItem in a loop in QLineEdit::editingFinished

Tags: c++, qt, widget, physics, qwidget

I am currently experimenting a bit with the Qt DataVisualization.

The goal is that I have a `QLineEdit` and when I exit it, I use the `QLineEdit::editingFinished` signal. And then I set the value that was entered to the selected `Bar`.

I get an error on line 46 when I start the second `for` loop when I try to access the `QBarDataItem`. I am getting a Read Access Violation there and I get the error on this line of the `qarraydatapointer.h` file from Qt:

```
bool needsDetach() const noexcept { return !d || d->needsDetach(); }
```

Here my code :

Main file:

```cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QFile>
#include "Window.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    
    // creates a window
    Window window;
    QFile file(app.applicationDirPath() + "/Test.txt");

    // Writes the x and y position of the selected Bar
    QObject::connect(window.getSeries(), &QBar3DSeries::selectedBarChanged, [&]() {
        if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)) {
            QTextStream stream(&file);
            stream << window.getSeries()->selectedBar().x() << ", "
                   << window.getSeries()->selectedBar().y() << ", "
                   << window.getSeries()->dataProxy()->rowAt(window.getSeries()->selectedBar().x())->data()->value() << "\n";
        }
    });

    QFile file1(app.applicationDirPath() + "/Data.txt");
    if (file1.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)) {
        QTextStream in(&file1);
        QBarDataRow *data = new QBarDataRow;
        while (!in.atEnd()) {
            QString line = in.readLine();
            *data << line.toFloat();
        }
        window.getSeries()->dataProxy()->addRow(data);
    }  
    
    window.show();
    file.close();
    file1.close();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Window.h:

```cpp
#ifndef WINDOW_H
#define WINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QtDataVisualization>

#define WIDTH 1400
#define HEIGHT 800

struct Data {
    Data() {
        data1 = new QBarDataRow;
        data2 = new QBarDataRow;
        data3 = new QBarDataRow;
        data4 = new QBarDataRow;
        data5 = new QBarDataRow;
    }
    ~Data() {
        delete data1;
        delete data2;
        delete data3;
        delete data4;
        delete data5;
    }

public:
    QList<QBarDataRow *> data{ data1, data2, data3, data4, data5 };
    QBarDataRow *data1;
    QBarDataRow *data2;
    QBarDataRow *data3;
    QBarDataRow *data4;
    QBarDataRow *data5;
};

class Window : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Window(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Window();
    QBar3DSeries *getSeries();

protected:
    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event) override;

private:
    Q3DBars *m_bars;
    QBar3DSeries *m_series;
    Data *m_data;
    QWidget *m_graph;
};

#endif // WINDOW_H
```

Window.cpp:

```cpp
#include "Window.h"
#include <QLineEdit>

static void setData(Data *data, QBar3DSeries *series) {
    *data->data1 << 1.0f << 3.0f << 6.5f << 5.0f << 2.2f;
    *data->data2 << 2.0f << 1.5f << 5.0f << 2.0f << 2.4f;
    *data->data3 << 3.0f << 2.5f << 4.0f << 1.0f << 3.4f;
    *data->data4 << 2.9f << 2.5f << 2.3f << 3.1f << 1.7f;
    //*data->data5 << 1.6f << 1.1f << 1.8f << 4.8f << 3.4f;

    series->dataProxy()->addRow(data->data1);
    series->dataProxy()->addRow(data->data2);
    series->dataProxy()->addRow(data->data3);
    series->dataProxy()->addRow(data->data4);
    //series->dataProxy()->addRow(data->data5);
}

Window::Window(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent) {
    // Initialising variables
    m_bars = new Q3DBars;
    m_series = new QBar3DSeries;
    m_data = new Data;

    setWindowTitle("Physik");
    resize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    m_bars->rowAxis()->setRange(0, 4);
    m_bars->columnAxis()->setRange(0, 4);
    m_bars->scene()->activeCamera()->setCameraPosition(30, 30);

    // set values which can then be seen
    setData(m_data, m_series);
    m_bars->addSeries(m_series);

    // Creates a QWidget, which is a child of the QMainWindow (this)
    m_graph = QWidget::createWindowContainer(m_bars, this);
    m_graph->setGeometry(0, 0, WIDTH * 0.7, HEIGHT);
    //--------------------------------------------------------------
    QLineEdit *lineEdit = new QLineEdit(this);
    lineEdit->setGeometry(WIDTH * 0.75, HEIGHT * 0.1, WIDTH * 0.85, HEIGHT * 0.15);
    connect(lineEdit, &QLineEdit::editingFinished, [&]() {
        QPoint position = m_series->selectedBar();
        for (size_t i{}; i < m_data->data.size(); ++i) {
            if (i == position.x()) {
                size_t j{};
                for (auto &value : *m_data->data[i]) {
                    if (j == position.y()) {
                        value.setValue(lineEdit->text().toFloat());
                    }
                    ++j;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    });
}

Window::~Window() {}

QBar3DSeries *Window::getSeries() {
    return m_series;
}

void Window::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event) {
    QMainWindow::resizeEvent(event);
    if (m_graph) {
        m_graph->resize(event->size().width() * 0.7, event->size().height());
    }
}
```

I tried to write my own `QBarDataItem` and `QBarDataRow` who inherit public both classes and tried to rewrite the functions, but it didn't work, and I really tried a lot of different stuff. But nothing worked, so I hope you can help me.

I know it's better to make this problem not too specific so that many people can help. In the end, I am only trying that I have a selected `Bar` and when I get out of the `QLineEdit` the value is then being set to the selected `Bar`.`enter code here`

Answer (score 0):

When your `m_data` object is constructed, its constructor implicitly initializes the `data` member first, which is receiving a *copy* of the `data1..data5` members *before* they have been initialized.  Those members are initialized *after* the `data` list is populated, and the pointers stored in the `data` list are never being updated later.  So the `data` list is left holding *invalid pointers*.

So, inside of your `editingFinished` lambda, when your loop retrieves a stored pointer from `m_data->data[i]` and tries to dereference that pointer, you experience *Undefined Behavior*, which in this case is resulting in a runtime error.

Try this instead for your `Data` struct:

```
struct Data {
    Data() {
        data1 = new QBarDataRow;
        data2 = new QBarDataRow;
        data3 = new QBarDataRow;
        data4 = new QBarDataRow;
        data5 = new QBarDataRow;

        //initialize the list here...
        data = QList<QBarDataRow *>{ data1, data2, data3, data4, data5 };
    }

    ~Data() {
        delete data1;
        delete data2;
        delete data3;
        delete data4;
        delete data5;
    }

public:
    //don't initialize the list here...
    //QList<QBarDataRow *> data{ data1, data2, data3, data4, data5 };
    QList<QBarDataRow *> data;
    QBarDataRow data1;
    QBarDataRow data2;
    QBarDataRow data3;
    QBarDataRow data4;
    QBarDataRow data5;
};
```

Also, there's no real need to `new`/`delete` the `data1..data5` members manually at all, eg:

```
struct Data {
    Data() {
        data = QList<QBarDataRow *>{ &data1, &data2, &data3, &data4, &data5 };
    }

    // or:
    // Data() : data{ &data1, &data2, &data3, &data4, &data5 } {}

public:
    QList<QBarDataRow *> data;
    QBarDataRow data1;
    QBarDataRow data2;
    QBarDataRow data3;
    QBarDataRow data4;
    QBarDataRow data5;
};
```

Or:

```
struct Data {
    QList<QBarDataRow *> data{ &data1, &data2, &data3, &data4, &data5 };
    QBarDataRow data1;
    QBarDataRow data2;
    QBarDataRow data3;
    QBarDataRow data4;
    QBarDataRow data5;
};
```

---

That being said, you also don't need the secondary loops at all, since you already know exactly which item to update:

```
connect(lineEdit, &QLineEdit::editingFinished, [&]() {
    QPoint position = m_series->selectedBar();
    int x = position.x(), y = position.y();
    if (x >= 0 && x < m_data->data.size()) {
        QBarDataRow *row = m_data->data[x];
        if (y >= 0 && y < row->size()) {
            (*row)[y].setValue(lineEdit->text().toFloat());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but now I get an Access violation reading location in line 48 where i set the new Value for the bar

Comment: Mo bugs, mo questions, @SnakezzGP . But before you ask another question make sure it's not something simple you could pick off with a debugger. A lot of new users get themselves banned by machine-gunning out trivial questions that the community doesn't see as particularly useful additions to the library of answers to questions that is Stack Overflow. Save your questions for the tough stuff when you really are stuck.

Comment: I am still getting the same error at the line where the value is set

Comment: Then there is something else wrong with your code that we are not seeing. You need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code and make sure all of your variables are doing what you expect them to do.

Comment: I know how to use a debugger. And i debugged through a few times. I think there is somewhere a const or something like that. But i dont now where